# What underlying psychological mechanisms could cause a person or a group to experience the bandwagon effect?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, bias, artificial-intelligence, hci

People in a target audience are likely to experience the [bandwagon effect](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/bandwagon-effect.asp) [1] because they rely on others' assessment of information. Overall, taking advantage of the bandwagon effect can be beneficial in a wide range of situations [2]. However, [reverse-bandwagon behaviors](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/11077/what-is-the-opposite-of-the-bandwagon-effect) are not always driven by the associated cognitive bias, which go against what is done by others.

A practical example of how the bandwagon effect can spread, appears in the case of the [medical sciences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medicine), which are generally viewed as objective, rigorous, and empirically-driven. Thus, less likely to be influenced by similar phenomena. Although the medical sciences are not commonly influenced by these phenomena, the new *hype* of a novel medical concept can promote the bandwagon effect. As a result of a large-scale bandwagon effect, some studies [3, 4] have demonstrated how a new medical concept can gain momentum and become mainstream. For instance, [Artificial Intelligence (AI)](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/learn/what-is-artificial-intelligence) is rapidly evolving into solutions for clinical practice [5], but the reality is that [the field has not yet fully embraced](https://www.forbes.com/sites/saibala/2020/02/03/artificial-intelligence-is-not-ready-for-the-intricacies-of-radiology) to clinical practice. Still, doctors and more and more open [6] for the introduction of AI in their clinical daily basis. Making it apparent the presence of the bandwagon effect, while denoting [other research problems](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/141375/62997).

For research purposes, the following question arise:

**What underlying psychological mechanisms could cause a doctor or a group of doctors to experience the bandwagon effect over the AI hype?**

## References

[1] Luckhoff C. (2021) Bandwagon Effect. In: Raz M., Pouryahya P. (eds) Decision Making in Emergency Medicine. Springer, Singapore. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-981-16-0143-9_9

[2] Howard J. (2019) Bandwagon Effect and Authority Bias. In: Cognitive Errors and Diagnostic Mistakes. Springer, Cham. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-93224-8_3

[3] Whelehan, D.F., Conlon, K.C. & Ridgway, P.F. Medicine and heuristics: cognitive biases and medical decision-making. Ir J Med Sci 189, 1477–1484 (2020). https://doi.org/10.1007/s11845-020-02235-1

[4] Landucci, F., Lamperti, M. A pandemic of cognitive bias. Intensive Care Med 47, 636–637 (2021). https://doi.org/10.1007/s00134-020-06293-y

[5] Francisco Maria Calisto, Carlos Santiago, Nuno Nunes, Jacinto C. Nascimento, Introduction of human-centric AI assistant to aid radiologists for multimodal breast image classification, International Journal of Human-Computer Studies, Volume 150, 2021, 102607, ISSN 1071-5819, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijhcs.2021.102607

[6] Nadarzynski, T. et al. (2019) ‘Acceptability of artificial intelligence (AI)-led chatbot services in healthcare: A mixed-methods study’, DIGITAL HEALTH.  https://doi.org/10.1177/2055207619871808

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. Isn't the answer to your question: *"the bandwagon effect*"? It sounds like you are asking about details how it works, on a personal level, perhaps. Also note that "experiencing" the bandwagon effect sounds odd to me. It's an effect.